# dynamic table query select

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Hello guys I want to create a dynamic table query to be updated on runtime. I have two postgis tables one that contains points--tablename(records) and one that contains polygons--tablename(OpDMA). This select query:

```
Create table Op_DMAConn as
SELECT pol.id as polygon_id, poi.id as point_id 
FROM "OpDMA" pol
LEFT JOIN records poi ON (ST_Intersects(poi.geom, pol.geom))
```

returns the polygon_id polygons and point_id of the points. I would like this query to be executed on runtime!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the 'EXECUTE' statement. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html

For example you can do that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_pointer(points_table_name varchar, polygon_table_name varchar)
 returns  table(polygon_id int, point_id int)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
declare
    final_query varchar;
begin
    query := 'SELECT ST_Contains(polygon.geom, point.geom)
    FROM public."'||points_table_name||'" point, public."'||polygon_table_name||'" polygon;'

    -- do what you have to do to make your query return you correct table

    return query execute final_query;
end
$$
;

select fn_pointer('table_name_1','table_name_2');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me what it does when new points are added, does it update the table or creates a new table ?

Comment: What this code provide : a not working version of the crucial part of what you need that is the dynamix query mechanism. In this code nothing is created nor updated in database. It is just a basic select that will be tried to be returned (and will fail due to the number of awaited column required by the return type of the function.

Comment: I have created a table with the results as I want them which returns the polygon id and point id this previous select query created just the id of the points and false or true if it is inside of a polygon. I will update my select query in the question, can you help me create this execute command?

Comment: Could you please follow those guidelines : it will be helpfull to answer you correctly and in the time that I have (not so much ;) ) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question